# Can't get internationalization to work with Django 1.5

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I am trying to make a website available in different languages. I am following some tutorial I found on GitHub (https://github.com/mjp/django-multi-language).

### views.py

```py
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


# ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
def index(request):

    # Rendering the page
    context = { 'foobar':_('Hello !') }
    response = render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
    request.session['django_language'] = 'fr'
    return response
```

### index.html

```html
{% load i18n %}
<p>{{ foobar }}</p>
```

### settings.py

```py
# Project path for further access
PROJECT_PATH = path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Locale paths
LOCALE_PATHS = (              # Next to the settings.py
    PROJECT_PATH+'/locale/',  # the time I find a better way to
)                             # avoid hard coded absolute path
```

Localization is quite straightforward, but my page keeps saying *Hello !* instead of *Bonjour !*.

---

## Edit

```
- documentation/
- locale/          <-- I want it here
- sources/
  - application1/
  - application2/
  - projectname/
    - settings.py
    - ...
    - locale/      <-- Currently here
- toolbox/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `request.session['django_langauge']` is not helpfull in this case. The `LocaleMiddleware` which I assume you have installed will parse that before the request gets to the `view` function. You should directly use the `translation` functions to change language for this.

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

def index(request):
    activate('fr')
    ....
    return response
```

Comment: About the relative path I have used for `LOCALE_PATHS`, is there any suggested way ? I'd like my root directory as such: `documentation/`, `locale/`, `sources/`, `toolbox`.

Comment: I think is good like that or use `path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale')`.

Comment: Usually `locale` should either be inside each `app` specific or in the root of your project. In your case in `sources`. If you wanted outside just put it there. with `path.dirname(path.dirname(PROJECT_PATH))` this will return the directory you want to put locale in.

Comment: I see the internationalization as something completely apart and thus the person who would be in charge of translating stuff wouldn't give a damn about the sources :/.

Comment: Why do you use `path.dirname` twice ?

Comment: To get the parent parent directory.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I went to docs.python.org and it says there that `path.dirname` returns the directory name (like `path.split` would do). I can't test right now, sorry for the questions if silly they are.

Comment: English isn't my mother tongue, got the wording wrong :/, thanks for the help though.